# Как отключить автоматическое подключение к сети?

Tags: windows, сеть, windows-10, администрирование

Можно ли заставить 10 винду не подключаться к сети на старте системы программно без выдергивания кабеля? Какие настройки надо прописать?

потом подключаться надо, если такая необходимость есть. Но надо программно, а не отключением устройств/выдёргиванием кабелей и проч..

просто хочу использовать ОС без подключения к сети, чтобы винда ничего не передавала куда не надо. На линуксе с этим проблем нет, подключение по запросу идёт, когда сам укажешь, а на винде ещё даже до логина в систему уже пакеты куда-то бегут.

---

@Эникейщик

> а потом подключаться надо или? Можно просто сетевой адаптер деактивировать.

Да, потом подключаться надо, если такая необходимость есть. Но надо программно, а не отключением устройств/выдёргиванием кабелей и проч..

@user7860670

> Это похоже на проблему XY.

Нет, просто хочу использовать ОС без подключения к сети, чтобы винда ничего не передавала куда не надо. На линуксе с этим проблем нет, подключение по запросу идёт, когда сам укажешь, а на винде ещё даже до логина в систему уже пакеты куда-то бегут.

Comment: а потом подключаться надо или? Можно просто сетевой адаптер деактивировать.

Comment: Это похоже на проблему XY.

Comment: Если стоит задача ограничения трафика, то выбранный механизм не ограничивает объём трафик, а лишь откладывает его передачу до момента включения сетевого интерфейса. Значит нужно искать иные способы: внешний межсетевой экран; программный МЭ стороннего производителя; отключение или удаление ПО, которое вызывает избыточный трафик и пр.